# Using XLS Formulas (Sum, avg ...) using Java

Tags: java, xls, jxl

How to use formula like sum, avg, max and min while generating XLS file using Java.

I am using jxl.write.*, i have see so many example for apache-poi. Is it possible to do the same using jxl?

```
Label label;
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
label = new Label(column, row, "sample");
Number number = new Number(column, row, 60);
excelSheet.addCell(label);
excelSheet.addCell(number);
```

Comment: You would like to your sum, avg in Java code or xls?

Comment: Show some code pls. What have you tried.

Comment: I am generating xls file using java, while generating xls file i want to calculate the sum / avg / max of some cells

Comment: That is big code File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got it from this link [Problem when using JXL Formula like SUM() AVG() STDEV() returns #VALUE! when it refers values from another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490216/problem-when-using-jxl-formula-like-sum-avg-stdev-returns-value-when-it)

```
  String filename = "C:\\input.xls";
  WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
  ws.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
  WritableWorkbook workbook = 
  Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename), ws);
  WritableSheet s = workbook.createSheet("Input", 0);
  WritableSheet s1 = workbook.createSheet("Output", 1);
  s1.addCell(new Number(3, 0, 5));
  s1.addCell(new Number(3, 1, 6));
  s1.addCell(new Number(3, 2, 1));
  s1.addCell(new Number(3, 3, 6));
  s1.addCell(new Number(3, 4, 1));
  Formula formula = new Formula(3,5,"AVERAGE(D1:D5)");
  s.addCell(formula);
```